# Drawing a graph with two functions

Tags: graphs

I would really like to have a graph as you can see on the picture below. But I do not have any idea how I can realize this with latex. I am sorry for asking you like this, but I am quite new with this stuff. I hope someone may help me. Thank you!!

[image]

Source of the picture: http://www.uni-saarland.de/fak1/fr12/albert/files/ss07/Spiel-Kap2.pdf

Comment: `pgfplots` or using `gnuplot` and exporting it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, one could add more eyecandy to it, but it should convey the proper message.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    enlargelimits=false,
    xlabel=$p$,ylabel=$\pi_1$,
    domain=0:1,xmin=0,xmax=1,
    ymin=0,ymax=4.2,
    no marks,clip=false]
    \addplot[dashed] { -x+3} node[above,sloped,pos=0.2] {$\pi_1((p,1-p),T)$};
    \addplot[dashed] {3*x+1} node[above,sloped,pos=0.7] {$\pi_1((p,1-p),H)$};
    \addplot[red] {ifthenelse(x>0.5,-x+3,3*x+1)};
    \draw[dotted,red] (axis cs:0,5/2) node[left] {$\underline{v} = \frac{5}{2}$}
      -| (axis cs:0.5,0) node[below] {$\hat{p} = \frac{1}{2}$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer (+1)  :-), however, it is good habits always  to document (in preamble) add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}` (this is today last version) to indicate which version of \pgflpots` is used. And with this version instead `(axis cs:0,5/2)` you can write just `(0,5/2)`

Comment: @Zarko True, but adding the latest `compat` might make the code fail on OP's machine due to outdated TeXlive.  Ubuntu 14.04LTS for example packages TL2013 and many users haven't yet updated to 16.04LTS.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I will try out how it works. Really, thank you!!

Comment: @hpz1719 Posting a thank-you comment is of course nice, but [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) and [accepting answers](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) is the preferred way here.